# How to make front-end angularjs code communicate to backend java code on same EC2

Tags: java, angularjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance on a private subnet.

I have a Java Spring-boot application deployed using nohup on it on port 8080

I have another front-end application in AngularJS which is run using grunt and pm2 on the same EC2 on port 9000.

The front end application communicates with the java backend on localhost.

In the front-end code, I use the `$http` library to call the java APIs like this:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/myserv/getdata',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': '*/*'
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  // processing data...
},
function (err) {
 console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

The EC2 instance itself is on a private network and It is exposed through an ELB which redirects all internet traffic to localhost port 9000 on EC2.

Now, when I open the application through my browser, I can see the UI correctly, but in the dev console, i gives error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So, I think it is not able to communicate with the backend API.

On the EC2, when I do a curl on `http://localhost:9000/home/` and on `http://localhost:8080/myserv/getdata`, both give correct response, so both the applications are running file, then why isn't the front-end able to communicate with the back end?

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS runs in the browser. The AngularJS application's version of "localhost" is always going to be your local laptop/desktop computer, while the Spring Boot's version of "localhost" is the EC2 server. So what you are trying to do is not going to work. Using "localhost" like this would only work when you are running everything on your local computer.

The Spring Boot application will have to be exposed so it can be accessed from every person's laptop/desktop computer that will be using your application. If this is a public application that means exposing it to the entire Internet.

The AngularJS application will need to be configured with the Internet address of the EC2 server.